# Issue with Executor Service, List size is always zero?

Tags: java

My Program is running successfully but I don't know why list size is always zero.Which should not be zero.
dummy text ==========================
dummy text ===========================
dummy text =========================

```
package ca.cgi.general;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Worker implements Runnable {

    Random random = new Random();
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Object lock1 = new Object();
    Object lock2 = new Object();

    private void StageOne() {
        synchronized (lock1) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list1.add(random.nextInt());
        }

    }

    private void StageTwo() {
        synchronized (lock2) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list2.add(random.nextInt());
            //System.out.println(list2.size());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            StageOne();
            StageTwo();
        }

    }

    public void decession() throws InterruptedException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Worker());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println("All task comleted");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Taken:" + (endTime - startTime));

        System.out.println("List1 " + list1.size());
        System.out.println("List2 " + list2.size());


    }

}

package ca.cgi.general;

public class TestThread {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new  Worker().decession();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create 3 instances of Worker: The first one is in the main. Its lists are never touched and eventually the ones you print in decision.

Inside decision method, you create two new Workers, each has its own lists. Each worker changes only its lists - but those changes are never reflected on the lists of the Main worker.

Long story short, you need to "share" those lists among all workers: make those lists static and final. This should resolve it.

Comment: you are most welcome. I would appreciate if you could vote me up